# Xpath CasperJS, take last element

Tags: xpath, click, casperjs

i have a problem with Xpath.

I have that :

```
<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" id="1 (fix but random)" aria-live="off" style="overflow: auto;">
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item"></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">standard 2014</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="1 (fix but random)__PackageId_option_selected" aria-selected="true">standard couple 2014</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Gratuit</li>
</ul>

<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" id="2 (fix but random)" aria-live="off" style="overflow: auto;">
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item"></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">standard 2014</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="1 (fix but random)__PackageId_option_selected" aria-selected="true">standard couple 2014</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Gratuit</li>
</ul>

<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" id="RANDOM" aria-live="off" style="overflow: auto;">
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item"></li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">standard 2014</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="1 RANDOM__PackageId_option_selected" aria-selected="true">standard couple 2014</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Gratuit</li>
</ul>
```

My question is simple : how can i click with casper on last < li > with standard 2014 ?
I try that :

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
this.click(x('//*ul[@class="k-list k-reset"]/li[text() = "standard 2014"]'))
```

But casperjs don't find.
Thank's for your help !

Comment: I haven't used casperjs, but your xpath looks invalid; specifically `//*ul`. Try removing the asterisk.

Comment: Yes ty @DanielHaley ,  but casper click on my first li :(
For click on last, i use last() 

this.click(x('//li[text() = "Gratuit" and last()]'));

But first li he click too.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding your xpath in parentheses and adding `[last()]` to the end. Like `(xpath)[last()]`

You should also remove the asterisk from `//*ul`

It should look like this:

```
this.click(x('(//ul[@class="k-list k-reset"]/li[text() = "standard 2014"])[last()]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check whether your X-path is valid or not in console of browser. like

```
$x('//a[contains(text(),"Cancel")]')
```